# Help finding an exercise (example?) referred to in SGA 4

Tags: reference-request

There is an appendix written by Bourbaki at the end of SGA 4, Exposé I. In section 2 of this appendix–titled "Univers et espèces de structures"–paragraph 3, you will find the following:

> Considérons alors la catégorie (-$\mathcal{E}$) définie au **§ 1, n$^{\circ}$ 2, ex. c)**.
> Comme les objets et les flèches de (-$\mathcal{E}$) sont des éléments de ,
> (-$\mathcal{E}$) est un couple de parties de , muni d’un quadruplet
> d’applications ; ce n’est pas, en général, un élément de . La
> notation  ∈ (-$\mathcal{E}$) voudra dire que  est un élément de  muni
> d’une structure d’espèce $\mathcal{E}$.

Where can I find the material referred to by § 1, n$^{\circ}$ 2, ex. c)? I can't seem to find it in SGA 4...Does it refer to the earlier books? Or perhaps some other source?